# Не могу добавить карту, созданную другим пользователем в Yandex api react, в доке ничего про это не написано

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Хотел до добавить к себе на сайт карту, созданную другим пользователем [такого](https://yandex.ru/maps/2/saint-petersburg/?ll=30.313207%2C59.922939&mode=usermaps&source=constructorLink&um=constructor%3A84fc535297ff47e6e99cabae2b323a330d10d1d6bc3cdbefdf4994dcd4719c28&z=11.35) типа, в официальной документации ничего про это не написано, как я могу реализовать это используя реакт

Comment: Карты, созданные в Конструкторе, добавляются на страницы в виде <iframe>. Вариант интеграции описан, например здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33913737/17361885